# Ember.RSVP.hash reload internal promises

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.RSVP.hash object being returned from the model hook in the route object. However, I'd like to periodically pull the data from the server and "refresh" or reload all the data with the new data from the server. How can this be done? Say it looks something like this:

```
model: function(params) {

        return new Ember.RSVP.hash({
            firstProp: Ember.$.getJSON(baseURL + 'firstProp/'),
            secondProp: Ember.$.getJSON(baseURL + 'secondProp/'),
            thirdProp: Ember.$.getJSON(baseURL + 'thirdProp/'),
        });
    }
```

and I want to be able to do something like

```
poll: function() {
      var _this = this;
      Ember.run.later( function() {
         _this.reload(); 
         _this.poll();
      }, 500);
   }.observes('didLoad')
```

sort of thing, except I can't just call `reload` because I'm not using ember-data but rather using jQuery to pull the properties into an `Ember.RSVP.hash`. So how do I reload each of the component properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the route's `refresh` method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh) to trigger the model hook again.

If you want to call it from the controller, you could expose the method with a route action.

Comment: Will that cause a visible refresh to the user?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "visible refresh". It will cause the route to transition through a loading state.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to just reload the model data. Causing the route to transition to a loading state shows the loading screen and causes a visible refresh. I'd just like to refresh the data if possible, the equivalent of calling `model.refresh()` with Ember data.